# How to upload Zabbix template using API

Tags: api, templates, zabbix

Does anyone know, how to upload Zabbix templates using API?

We are trying to use java and Zabbix 2.0 API.
Our goal is to get Zabbix graphs (png pictures) by different hosts and to display them on our monitoring page. We need to have a possibility to customize monitored parameters for different hosts by using templates. And we have faced with a monitoring templates to zabbix server uploading issue.

There are two different API calls:

1. **configuration.import** (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/configuration/import) Using this we can upload our template to zabbix server, but we can't see it on UI or use it in any other way. Zabbix server reports "true" and this means that template successfully uploaded. But we can't find it anywhere.
2. **template.create** (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/template/create) Using template.create we can create template entity on zabbix server, but we can't see any parameters for the template data itself - we can't upload our file using this.

Does anyone know how to tight together these two API calls and how to get configured zabbix template on zabbix server?

Answer (score 1):

so ehm.. since I've been using template export+import scripts in TEST to PROD and vice versa (at my previous job) here's a whole python script that helps with the import task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Import XML configuration files using Zabbix API:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/configuration/import
"""
import argparse
from urllib import request
import json
import sys
from pprint import pformat
import os
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

def zbxrequest(url, method, auth, params):

    if params is None:
        params = {}
    data = { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": method, "auth": auth, "params": params }
    # Convert to string and then to byte
    data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    req = request.Request(args.url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=data)
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
    # Get string
    resp = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
    # Convert to object
    resp = json.loads(resp, encoding='utf-8')
    return resp


try:
    # Parse command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Import XML configuration files using Zabbix API')
    parser.add_argument('template_file')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', required=True, help='user name')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', '--pass', required=True, help='password', metavar='PASSWORD')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--url', default='http://127.0.0.1:80/api_jsonrpc.php',
                        help='Zabbix API URL, default is http://127.0.0.1:80/api_jsonrpc.php')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # TODO: add API version check
    # r=zbxrequest(args.url, method="apiinfo.version", auth=None, params={})
    # print(r)

    # Get authentication token
    # https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/user/login
    auth_result = zbxrequest(args.url, method="user.login", auth=None,
                             params={"user": args.user, "password": args.password})

    # If authentication was not OK
    if 'result' not in auth_result:
        raise Exception('ERROR: auth failed\n' + pformat(auth_result))

    auth_token = auth_result['result']

    # Read template file content
    with open(args.template_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        source = f.read()

    # Set import parameters, including template file content
    params = {'format': 'xml',
              'rules': {'groups': {'createMissing': True},
                        'hosts': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'items': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'applications': {'createMissing': True},
                        'templates': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'templateLinkage': {'createMissing': True},
                        'templateScreens': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'discoveryRules': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'triggers': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'graphs': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'valueMaps': {'createMissing': True},
                        'images': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'maps': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True},
                        'screens': {'createMissing': True, 'updateExisting': True}
                        },
              'source': source
              }

    # https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/configuration/import
    import_result = zbxrequest(args.url, method="configuration.import", auth=auth_token, params=params)
    # Something like: {'id': 1, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': True}

    if 'result' in import_result and import_result['result']:
        print('SUCCESS: configuration import')
    else:
        raise Exception('ERROR: configuration import failed\n' + pformat(import_result))

    exit_code = 0

except Exception as e:

   print(str(e), file=sys.stderr)
   exit_code=1

finally:
    # Logout to prevent generation of unnecessary open sessions
    # https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/user/logout
    if 'auth_token' in vars():
        zbxrequest(args.url, method="user.logout", auth=auth_token, params={})
```

and this is how you would call such script in bash:

```
python3 ./import.py --url $URL/api_jsonrpc.php --user $USER --password $PASSWD $TEMPLATE_FILE
```

it goes without saying you need to satisfy all the dependencies in python for this to run OK. Also I've last used it on zabbix 4.0 LTS & do not recall who's the original author - if someone finds out I'll mention him/her here to get the credit for creating this.